# Anylogic send seized reourcesses based on different resource pool if other resource pool is busy

Tags: java, json, anylogic

I have created a flow that Seize resources from another resource pool if other resource pool is busy.  How do use send seized resources from a pool that differs if one or the other is busy?

I hope you van help :-)

See attached pictures

[image: seize block]

[image: send seized resourceses]

Comment: sorry, what is your question? This is not very clear :)

Comment: what happens to the resources from each pool now?